# How to insert , MapReduce output into HBASE using same program

Tags: hadoop, pdf, mapreduce, hbase

I wrote a program which take pdf as an input and produces text output as a whole. I want to load this text in hbase using same program, is there any way to do it.Any help will be appreciable

```
//Driver Class
package com.tcs;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser;

public class PdfInputDriver {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,InterruptedException, ClassNotFoundException 
    {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        GenericOptionsParser parser = new GenericOptionsParser(conf, args);
        args = parser.getRemainingArgs();
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        Job job = new Job(conf, "Pdftext");
        job.setJarByClass(PdfInputDriver.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(LongWritable.class);
        job.setInputFormatClass(PdfInputFormat.class);
        job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);
        FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
        job.setMapperClass(WordCountMapper.class);
        job.setReducerClass(WordCountReducer.class);


        System.out.println(job.waitForCompletion(true));
    }
}

//InputFormatClass
package com.tcs;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.InputSplit;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.RecordReader;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskAttemptContext;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;

public class PdfInputFormat extends FileInputFormat<Object, Object> {

    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
    @Override
    public RecordReader createRecordReader(
            InputSplit split, TaskAttemptContext context) throws IOException,
            InterruptedException {

        return new PdfRecordReader();
    }

}

//PDF Record Reader class
package com.tcs;

import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataInputStream;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.InputSplit;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.RecordReader;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskAttemptContext;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileSplit;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFTextStripper;

public class PdfRecordReader extends RecordReader<Object, Object> {

    private String[] lines = null;
    private LongWritable key = null;
    private Text value = null;

    @Override
    public void initialize(InputSplit genericSplit, TaskAttemptContext context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        FileSplit split = (FileSplit) genericSplit;
        Configuration job = context.getConfiguration();
        final Path file = split.getPath();

        /*
         * The below code contains the logic for opening the file and seek to
         * the start of the split. Here we are applying the Pdf Parsing logic
         */

        FileSystem fs = file.getFileSystem(job);
        FSDataInputStream fileIn = fs.open(split.getPath());
        PDDocument pdf = null;
        String parsedText = null;
        PDFTextStripper stripper;
        pdf = PDDocument.load(fileIn);
        stripper = new PDFTextStripper();
        parsedText = stripper.getText(pdf);
        //String delims = "[ ]";
        this.lines = parsedText.split("/n");
        }

    @Override
    public boolean nextKeyValue() throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        if (key == null) {
            key = new LongWritable();
            key.set(1);
            value = new Text();
            value.set(lines[0]);
        } else 
        {
            int temp = (int) key.get();
            if (temp < (lines.length - 1)) {
                int count = (int) key.get();
                value = new Text();
                value.set(lines[count]);
                count = count + 1;
                key = new LongWritable(count);
            } else {
                return false;
            }

        }
        if (key == null || value == null) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public LongWritable getCurrentKey() throws IOException,
            InterruptedException {

        return key;
    }

    @Override
    public Text getCurrentValue() throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public float getProgress() throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {

    }

}

//Mapper Class
package com.tcs;


import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;


public class WordCountMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, LongWritable>
{

    protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
         throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    context.write(value, key);
}
}


//Reducer Class
package com.tcs;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;

public class WordCountReducer extends Reducer<Object, Object, Object, Object> {
    protected void reduce(Text key, Iterable<LongWritable> values,
            Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {


            context.write(key, new WordCountReducer());
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `context.write(key, new WordCountReducer())` supposed to do?

Comment: Please avoid that, its just for testing something, the output of the following code is conversion of pdf into text.(PDF present into hdfs), my concern is to load output data into hbase

Comment: Perhaps looking at the HBase manual will help: http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#mapreduce.example

Answer (score 0):

i think you are making jar file of it. Just use the part-r-00000 file of what you have generated from mapreduce output.
create 'table'